# Jira: Ticket showing as resolved with Resolution set to None

Tags: jira

I have a Jira Ticket which has the resolution set to None, however the Ticket is showing the strikethrough that is normally assigned if a resolution value has been set.

How do I reset the ticket to a pre resolution state (eg not showing the strikethrough the ticket name? )

Comment: What sort of project is this? If it is one of the next gen projects check if your status is the last in the board columns. The last status is associated with the done status category so could be triggering the strike through.

Comment: HI no the ticket is in our "in Dev" status which, in the workflow, is only the 3rd of 11 status.